# Overflowing a page-container's background-color using CSS margin and padding

Tags: html, css

I am working on a the html/css of the landing page of a website/application and I don't want to make too many changes. The templates are rendered using Jinja2 and the homepage extends from a page_template.html. There are many page templates that extend the page_template.html so I would like to fiddle as little as possible with it. The designer would like to have the background-color of a div (or two) on the homepage extend out over the entire width of the browser no matter the browser/screen resolution. The page template has a `page-container` id wrapping around the entire content like so.

```
#page-container {
  background-position: 0 85px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If I want to extend a div to go outside this width of 1200px I decided to try something like this:

```
.overflow {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

And do something like this:

```
<div id="page-container">
  <div class="overflow">
   Content
  </div>
</div>
```

And it seems to work. And it works well enough for this webapp ( I think ). However it breaks the responsiveness of the page in that the divs which have this `.overflow` class do not resize when the browser is made smaller. Is their a better way to do this? And is their a way to do this without affecting the responsiveness?

Comment: It seems fine. What do you mean by "..not resize" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the :before and :after pseudo-elements.

Assuming the markup you used in your question, this CSS should do the trick:

```
.overflow { position: relative; }

.overflow:before,
.overflow:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 9999px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #c0ffee;
}

.overflow:before { left: 100%; }
.overflow:after { right: 100%; }
```

You may also want to consider adding overflow-x: hidden to your body and html elements to prevent horisontal scroll bars:

```
body, html { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Browser support for this is essentially IE8+ so you can expect it to work on mostly every browser.

Comment: Thanks!, This seems to work well. I do get two vertical scroll-bars. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Two vertical scroll bars? I have never seen this behaviour, however it seems like others experience similar problems, for instance:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132746/two-vertical-scrollbars-in-firefox-when-using-overflow-xhidden

Comment: Hmmm, yes I see. The suggested answers from from that question didn't work for me so I removed this line in the CSS: `html { overflow-y: scroll;}`. Do you think I will create potential problems by removing this line?

Comment: I cannot say for sure but i never/extremely rarely use overflow-y: scroll on anything so it shouldn't cause you any problems removing it.